# ReactJS re render/redraw the server generated view

Tags: php, codeigniter, reactjs

So I have this app, Lets say it is similar to Facebook posting something on your wall,

Everything is rendered on a PHP server / Codeigniter Framework and sent to the client, I need these posts to be rendered using ReactJS because I have awesome things I like to do inside each of these post

1. Like
2. Comment
3. Edit / Report

I DO NOT WANT TO USE V8JS, because the client can not play with the php servers, just need the php script to work that's it,

Any thoughts how I could do this guys? Thanks so much,

One Idea is to may be,

Load the posts as server rendered and then do a GET request and render the same posts again using ReactJS? Will that work?

Or is there a way to attach all ReactJS functions and events to a server rendered html page?

Answer (score 0):

For React on the client/web browser to attach to an existing DOM structure (that was server rendered for example), it uses an attribute called `data-react-checksum` which is added to the root DOM element. Calling `React.renderComponentToString` for example will include this attribute.

```
<div data-react-checksum="452232529">
```

When you call `renderElement` on the same root element, React executes as normal calling `render`, etc. But, at the end of the `render` cycle, the `data-react-checksum` is compared to what was locally computed. If the value matches what was already in the DOM (provided by the server), the Virtual DOM attaches to the existing DOM elements. But to do that, as I mentioned it must match exactly.

Further, you'd need to also include the `data-reactid` attribute on the DOM elements that would be normally associated with React's virtual DOM.

If you can't execute the React render pipeline on the web server, you should rely on using Ajax to fetch the data. You could render the entire page via PHP, then fetch the data on the client and re-render the page. But, you'll need to decide if that makes sense for your application and users.

I'd suggest you consider just using React for the interactive sections of your web page, and construct those entire on the client as needed.

Comment: If you see this https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/9249/ see the html and how can I use the reactJS t re-render the html sent from the server ? Please update the fiddle :)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You'd need to write React components that mirrored the structure your PHP code created. There's nothing in the jsfiddle to update.

Comment: @user3656084 if you generate the html in php on the server, and you want to render the same stuff in react.js, you need to write everything twice. This is why people run JS on the server, and if you can't do it there are no other shortcuts.